# Return value for setTimeout function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

Hi all when i am executing this piece of code i am getting 40 in my console log can some one plese explain me why

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 300000)
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting on the console is the `id` returned by `setTimeout()`. If you run that code again you might get different value. We cannot predict this `id`, it is random.

If you want to print the values from 0-9 using `setTimeout()`, you need to take care of scope.

Using `bind()`:

```js
console.log('before loop');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.i);
  }.bind({
    i: i
  }), 1000)
}
console.log('after loop');
```

Using closures:

```js
console.log('before loop');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i); //<-- parameter i
    }, 1000);
  })(i); //<-- i from loop scope
}
console.log('after loop');
```

Print in increasing order of timeout.

```js
console.log('before loop');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.i);
  }.bind({
    i: i
  }), 100 * i); //<-- note `* i`
}
console.log('after loop');
```

Comment: Thanks Man , this Id can we predict this or rendom  . because when i am running my code again and again i am getting values as 40 50 60 ....

Answer (score 0):

Your code will print 10 after 300.000 milliseconds.

Try setting it to a shorter period and you will see 10 printed.

What you probably see is linenumber in the console.

Answer (score 0):

> when I am executing this piece of code I am getting 40 in my console log

The reason is that `setTimeout()` moves the function from the execution queue, it will only be invoked after JavaScript has finished with the current execution queue.
[`Understanding JavaScript Timers`](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/understanding-javascript-timers/)